# tryton file not found when opening database - looking in site-packages rather than directory in PYTHONPATH

Tags: python-2.7, tryton

tryton V3.8 on MAC.  I have a database "steve" with trytond running TCP/IP.  When doing database connect in tryton client, I get the following result as the last line in the error window: "IOError: File not found : /site-packages/trytond/modules/product/tryton.cfg"

In ~/.bash_profile, I have: 
    export PYTHONPATH=~/bryants:$PYTHONPATH 
where ~/bryants has a **init**.py file, and all modules are beneath it.

There is a tryton.cfg file in the ~/bryants/product directory.  Why isn't it looking in the ~/bryants directory?  Why isn't it being found?

Answer (score 1):

Tryton search modules only in the subdirectory `modules` from its installation path or for the entry points `trytond.modules` But it does not use the *PYTHONPATH* to detect modules.
So you must move the modules under the "modules" directory or you must install the modules with `python setup.py install` (or `python setup.py develop`).